# Why is plus(+) decoded to space ( ) in url path with springboot rest controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, undertow, tomcat8.5

When calling GET `http://localhost:8080/things/ZhaD2lk27XQPRJtwrABltd+UTWXcbnY%2FTrpxGP7VDVo=` my Spring Boot application RestController with a request handler like this:

```
  @RequestMapping("/things/{thingId}")
  public ResponseEntity<Thing> getThing(
      @PathVariable String thingId) {

    System.out.println("thingId=" + thingId);
  ...
```

results in the following being printed `ZhaD2lk27XQPRJtwrABltd UTWXcbnY/TrpxGP7VDVo=` instead of what I would have expected `ZhaD2lk27XQPRJtwrABltd+UTWXcbnY/TrpxGP7VDVo=`.

As you can see, the plus is being turned into a space.  This should not happen with the path part, only the query part.  This is why the Spring `UriComponentsBuilder.build().encode()` I'm using to build the URL doesn't turn the plus into `%2B`.

I needed to tweak the application already to get the encoded slash (/) to work.  See [REST Endpoint unreachable if ID in URL contains %2F](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1583) for details.

I'm using SpringBoot 1.4.4.RELEASE which uses Tomcat embed 8.5.11.
I have tried calling the service from Spring RestTemplate, Postman and Chrome. Same results in all cases, the plus is turned into a space

Comment: Are you typing the URL in the browser ? or are you invoking your service with js ? or are you invoking your service from a java client ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve after identifying that my IDE had automagically added spring-boot-starter-undertow to the POM file.  I did not exclude spring-boot-starter-tomcat from spring-boot-starter-web so I'm not sure what was happening under the covers but removing the spring-boot-starter-undertow dependency fixed the issue.